# Activar una función de Javascript (modo noche) cuando detecté las preferencias del usuario

Tags: javascript, css, web

Hola saludos cordiales estoy aprendiendo Javascript, tengo un script que activa el modo oscuro, llamando un CSS con su estilo por medio de un interruptor, mi consulta es: existe una posibilidad de activarlo cuando el usuario tenga activado el modo oscuro en su navegador sin que tenga que activar el interruptor, gracias aqui está el código:

```
var darkMode;

if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode')) {  
  // if dark mode is in storage, set variable with that value
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('dark-mode');  
} else {  
  // if dark mode is not in storage, set variable to 'light'
  darkMode = 'light';  
}

// set new localStorage value
localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', darkMode);

if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') == 'dark') {
  // if the above is 'dark' then apply .dark to the body
  $('body').addClass('dark');
  // hide the 'dark' button
  $('.dark-button').hide();
  // show the 'light' button
  $('.light-button').show();
}

// Toggle dark UI

$('.dark-button').on('click', function() {  
  $('.dark-button').hide();
  // set stored value to 'dark'
  localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'dark');
});

$('.light-button').on('click', function() {  
  $('.light-button').hide();
  $('.dark-button').show();
  $('body').removeClass('dark');
  // set stored value to 'light'
  localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'light');   
});
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda como siempre

NOTA: Quiero detectar el modo oscuro por el mismo Javascript utilizando:

```
const ejemplo = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías analizar la propiedad `.matches` de [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
// Devolverá verdadero o falso
let darkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

// ¿Activar estilo de modo oscuro?
if(darkMode) {
    $('body').addClass('dark');
} else {
    /*
     * Si el usuario no seleccionó modo oscuro en el navegador
     * aquí podrías incluir los botones y la lógica para manejarlo por localStorage
     */
}
```

No estoy seguro que funcione porque no lo he probado, pero podrías intentar "escuchar" cambios en preferencias del usuario con [.addListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener):

```
// Crear matchMedia
let eventDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
// Función para aplicar cambios
const isDark = (e) => {
    if(e.matches) {
        // Agregar clase
        $('body').addClass('dark');
    } else {
        // Quitar clase
        $('body').removeClass('dark');
    }
};
// Escuchar cambios en matchMedia
eventDark.addListener(isDark);
```

Es probable que debas adaptar ambos códigos, uno para detectar la configuración inicial y, este último, para cuando haya cambios como el que mencionaste en tu comentario.

Comment: Gracias es una manera mucho más intuitiva, el único problema en si, por ejemplo: si esta activado el modo oscuro en el navegador, y el usuario o el sistema operativo cambia de modo por uso horario que tenga configurado el usuario, si la pagina sigue abierta no se actualizan los colores hay que refrezcar la página

Comment: No habías especificado esa posibilidad en la pregunta, pero ya está actualizada la respuesta.