# Mantener tema Oscuro al Refrescar y Auto-Detectar tema del OS

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo este código JS que activa/desactiva el modo Oscuro mediante un toggle HTML.

Dicho código funciona con `claro.css` y `dark.css` y agrega la clase `dark-mode` al body.

Necesito que si el usuario elige el tema oscuro, se mantenga aunque refresque la página. Sé que es con Localstorage pero desconozco como implementarlo.

```
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function() {
           var darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#theme_mode_dark');
           var lightModeToggle = document.querySelector('#theme_mode_light');
           darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
             KTApp.setThemeMode("dark", function() {
               darkModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
               lightModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
             });
           });
           lightModeToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
             KTApp.setThemeMode("light", function() {
               darkModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
               lightModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
             });
           });
         });
```

**La segunda cuestión es:**

¿Cómo detectar el tema del sistema operativo del usuario y aplicarlo automáticamente?

Necesito una opción que no sea usar CSS `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` porque cómo dije, son 2 archivos css separados. Encontré esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70516556/15465836) en stackoverflow, y me funciona bien, pero no sé si es la forma correcta de hacerlo y si afecta los tiempos de carga?

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿La primera cuestión no es lo que ya hicimos aquí con el localStorage? -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519019/toggle-para-dark-mode-html

Comment: @masterguru si! Lo que pasa es que este código también cambia los iconos del toggle al tocarlos (y la animación) y no supe cómo adaptarle el localstorage del otro código al nuevo :( (antes de hacer la pregunta en stackoverflow habia hecho ya la pregunta en el foro de soporte del desarrollador)

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/424197/54039) para saber cómo almacenar el estilo seleccionado en localStorage y  [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/438404/54039) para detectar si en el navegador se seleccionó el modo oscuro.

Comment: @Triby Gracias, el asunto de detectar el tema del OS funciona, sin embargo al tocar el botón para volver al tema light, este no funciona.  (Aclaro que están en <script> separados. [Este es el Jsfiddle de mi adaptación del detectado del tema del OS](https://jsfiddle.net/hwmy9uzg/). 
Al que de plano no supe hacerlo funcionar es al asunto del Localstorage.

Comment: @masterguru crees que puedas ayudarme con el asunto del Localstorage al nuevo código? Te lo agradecería mucho :(. Si es que te animas, aquí te dejo [Mi Jsfiddle con el código html del botón y del Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/9pjm5hkt/).

Comment: Recarga la página y recomprueba mi respuesta, habia puesto mal el localStorage.setItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta pregunta viene a ser un calco de [la anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519019/toggle-para-dark-mode-html), con unas pequeñas modificaciones.

Creo que la respuesta que estás buscando vendria a ser esta:

```
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function() {
  var darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#theme_mode_dark');
  var lightModeToggle = document.querySelector('#theme_mode_light');

  if (localStorage.getItem("tema") !== null) {
    tema = localStorage.getItem("tema")
    if (tema == "light") {
      KTApp.setThemeMode("light", function() {
        darkModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
        lightModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
      });
    } else {
      KTApp.setThemeMode("dark", function() {
        darkModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
        lightModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
      });
    }
  }

  darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    KTApp.setThemeMode("dark", function() {
      darkModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
      lightModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
    });
    tema = 'dark'
    localStorage.setItem("tema", tema)
  });
  lightModeToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    KTApp.setThemeMode("light", function() {
      darkModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
      lightModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
    });
    tema = 'light'
    localStorage.setItem("tema", tema)
  });

});
```

**Modificaciones:**

1. Por un lado se ha agregado este trozo de código que determina si ya habia algo guardado en el localStorage previamente, y en ese caso, si es el tema light entonces le aplica lo mismo que haces al pulsar el botón toggle que ya tenias, y lo mismo pero para el dark en el `else` del mismo condicional:

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("tema") !== null) {
    tema = localStorage.getItem("tema")
    if (tema == "light") {
      KTApp.setThemeMode("light", function() {
        darkModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
        lightModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
      });
    } else {
      KTApp.setThemeMode("dark", function() {
        darkModeToggle.classList.add('d-none');
        lightModeToggle.classList.remove('d-none');
      });
    }
  }
```

2. Lo demás viene a ser lo mismo que en la anterior respuesta, es decir, detectamos el tema que está siendo activado mediante el click asignándolo a la variable **tema** y al final de cada función click lo guardamos en el localStorage mediante la instrucción:

```
localStorage.setItem("tema", tema)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciona a la perfección amigo

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro. Hoy he tenido que hacer algo similar en una web que estoy desarrollando y la verdad es que ya lo tenia por la mano :-)